# In React Passing ID From one Page to another it is passing URL but not pass in API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to Pass Id from One page to another it is pass in URL Parameter but it pass a null value in API URL. This is my First Page

```
   <Link to={"/GroupsDetail/?group_Id="+item.group_Id} title="Details" >Details</Link>&nbsp;
```

This is my second Page,

```
 submit= () => {
      const urll = new URL(window.location.href);
      const Id = urll.searchParams.get("group_Id");
              
              console.log(Id);
        let url = 'http://localhost:XXXXX/api/Group/GroupDetailsDisplay?group_Id='+Id;
  My Output is,
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
let history = useHistory();

history.push({
  pathname: '/home',
  state: {  // location state
    id: 123, 
  },
});
```

or

```
<Link to={{
      pathname: '/home',
       state: { id: 123 }
    }}> My Link </Link>
```

And to get the value of `id` :

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const location = useLocation();

console.log(location.state.id)
```

Comment: I already Tried this @Walidum it is not work Same error exists.

Comment: I'm facing the same Issue. Null value passing in API but it hit the API